# How to change redirect location in drupal

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I am New in drupal.
i have these two pages link in which two forms are setup. now i just want to change current submitted redirect link. How which file i have to edit from ftp or either which or if is it possible from admin let me know.
Thanks help appreciated.

http://plp.bm/action/membership

http://plp.bm/action/contribute

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the webform module for your forms, you can simply change the redirection location of your forms under yoursite.bm/node/id-of-your-node-containing-webform/webform/configure. You can change the redirection location to a custom url, a confirmation page containing the confirmation message or use the default setting which is "no redirect".

Answer (score 0):

To change the form redirection after on click of submit function.

`function _form_sumbit_fun_name () {
  //Do stuffs here.
  $form_state['redirect'] = 'page_url';
}`
It will redirect to page with specified url.